# I am returning a fatal error function must be a string in my php webhook for database fulfillment

Tags: php, webhooks, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am returning a fatal error saying function must be a string in my webhook database fulfillment. I want to be able to read and write to MySQL database

```
    $firstname
(isset($update["queryResult"]["parameters"]["firstname"])
? $update["queryResult"]["parameters"]["firstname"]
:null
);
    $lastname
(isset($update["queryResult"]["parameters"]["lastname"])
?$update["queryResult"]["parameters"]["firstname]
:null
);
    $policynumber
(isset($update["queryResult"]["parameters"]["policynumber"])
?$update["queryResult"]["parameters"]["policynumber"]
:null
);
    $id
(isset($update["queryResult"]["parameters"]["id"])
?$update["queryResult"]["parameters"]["id"]
:null
);
```

I must be able to read and write to my database but instead it is returning the fatal error on these lines of code. I would appreciate your help

Comment: Hi, can you make your code more readble ?

Comment: Hi, i am not sure how I am supposed to do that, im still new to php and also on this platform. any suggestions on how I can achieve that

Comment: Are you assigning value to $firstname variable?

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to get the value from the user input from the dialogflow bot

Answer (score 0):

just assign the value to the variable

```
$firstname = (isset($update["queryResult"]["parameters"]["firstname"])?$update["queryResult"]["parameters"]["firstname"]:null);
$lastname = (isset($update["queryResult"]["parameters"]["lastname"])?$update["queryResult"]["parameters"]["firstname"]:null);
$policynumber = (isset($update["queryResult"]["parameters"]["policynumber"])?$update["queryResult"]["parameters"]["policynumber"]:null);
$id = (isset($update["queryResult"]["parameters"]["id"])?$update["queryResult"]["parameters"]["id"]:null);
```